# Fail to authenticate via SoundCloud, sign-in callback is trying to access a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soundcloud, angularjs-1.6

*SoundCloud SDK v3.1.2*

I registered my App approximately 1 year ago.

Today I discovered that my SoundCloud (SC) sign-in stopped working.

When I click on the button the SC pop-up appears with message "*Allow “domain.com” access to your SoundCloud account?*" I click `connect` and get the callback pop-up with the message "*This popup should automatically close in a few seconds*". The callback pop-up never closes. And in the dev console (for the callback pop-up) I see the following errors:

**Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)**

`VM2980 callback.html?code=3717208…&state=SoundCloud_Dialog_508d9:7 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. 
at onload (http://domain.com/callback.html?code=3717208cc602aba6cc0195157ecd2b6b&state…8d9#access_token=1-166020-17988851-e8f6b064d7ccd4&scope=non-expiring:7:105)
    onload @ VM2980 callback.html?code=3717208…&state=SoundCloud_Dialog_508d9:7`

**Firefox 50.1.0**
`Error: Permission denied to access property "SC" callback.html:1:1`
[Learn More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied)

My callback.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1);">
    <p>
      This popup should automatically close in a few seconds
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript function (in AngularJS 1.6 component controller) that is triggered by a button on my page:

```
... 
      this.connect_sc = function () {
        debugger;
      // initiate auth popup
        SC.connect().then(function () {
          debugger;
          return SC.get('/me');
        }).then(function (me) {
          debugger;
          userPerma = me.permalink;
          setScUi(me.username, me.avatar_url);
          getPlaylists();
        });
      };
...
```

I tried to debug it putting some breakpoints. Here I don't get SC promise executed, it breaks only on the first `debugger;` after I click on my button.

Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have the page, domain, and callback URI [registered with SoundCloud?](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps/new)

Comment: Yes, sure, I have. And the redirect URI is correct, I checked. Besides, the sign-in worked before. Offcourse, it is possible I broke it somehow. But I don't see how. I don't get SC promise executed, it never breaks here: `SC.connect().then(function () { debugger; return SC.get('/me');})`

Comment: @Santi I've just found out that SC has a new way to register Apps. I registered approximately 1 year ago. And I built the latest SDK. Maybe something changed there.

Comment: See this answer for a possible workaround, if you control the content of both the frame and the parent window: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/1288121

Comment: Otherwise you are probably going to have to use the new app registration process SoundCloud offers.

Comment: @mopsyd I guess it is not possible to implement this workaround since I'm not an owner of SoundCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me.

I fixed it with a redirection. When I was in my website without the "www" it didn't work because the callback is registered with "www".

I added a redirection to only have my website with "www" and now it works well!

Hope it'll help.